# Data Encoding for Training in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, neural-network, backpropagation, perceptron

I have converted `349,900` words from a dictionary file to md5 hash. Sample are below:

```
74b87337454200d4d33f80c4663dc5e5
594f803b380a41396ed63dca39503542
0b4e7a0e5fe84ad35fb5f95b9ceeac79
5d793fc5b00a2348c3fb9ab59e5ca98a
3dbe00a167653a1aaee01d93e77e730e
ffc32e9606a34d09fca5d82e3448f71f
2fa9f0700f68f32d2d520302906e65ce
1c9b32ff1b53bd892b87578a11cbd333
26a10043bba821303408ebce568a2746
c3c32ff3481e9745e10defa7ce5b511e
```

I want to train a neural network to decrypt a hash using just simple architecture like MultiLayer Perceptron. Since all hash value is of length 32, I was thingking that the number of input nodes is 32, but the problem here is the number of output nodes. Since the output are words in the dictionary, it doesn't have any specific length. It could be of various length. That is the reason why Im confused on how many number of output nodes shall I have.

How will I encode my data, so that I can have specific number of output nodes?

I have found a paper [here](http://ijarcsse.com/Before_August_2017/docs/papers/Volume_6/3_March2016/V6I3-0271.pdf) in this link that actually decrypt a hash using neural network. The paper said

> The input to the neural network is the encrypted text that is to be decoded. This is fed into the neural network either in bipolar or binary format. This then traverses through the hidden layer to the final output layer which is also in the bipolar or binary format (as given in the input). This is then converted back to the plain text for further process.

How will I implement what is being said in the paper. I am thinking to limit the number of characters to decrypt. Initially , I can limit it up to `4` characters only(just for test purposes).

My input nodes will be `32` nodes representing every character of the  hash. Each input node will have the (ASCII value of the each_hash_character/256). My output node will have 32 nodes also representing binary format. Since 8 bits/8 nodes represent one character, my network will have the capability of decrypting characters up to 4 characters only because (32/8) = 4. (I can increase it if I want to. ) Im planning to use 33 nodes. Is my network architecture feasible? `32 x 33 x 32`? If no, why? Please guide me.

Comment: FYI, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135211/can-a-neural-network-crack-hashing-algorithms.

Comment: @JuliusVainora --> Yes Im aware of it, but I have to do it as a proof of concept. In fact a paper has done it already. I just have to know how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

You could map the word in the dictionary in a vectorial space (e.g. bag of words, word2vec,..). In that case the words are encoded with a fix length. The number of neurons in the output layer will match that length.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please give me some sample data of( words to vector)? Im not yet familiar with it.

Comment: If you are interest in the theory I would suggest to watch the Stanford course on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQQ-W_63UgQ

A good tutorial is here:
http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/

Finally if you are programming in python look for the gensim library. It is full of easy tutorial that shows how to use the word2vec

Comment: In your case I believe that Bag of words is a better approach, as you don't have to assume a syntactic relationship between the words. So please give a look here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-bag-words-model/

Comment: Why do you think bag of words? In BOW, it look at the histogram of the words within the text. Can I make a histogram of characters within a word?

Comment: @Eliyah  I suppose that you can do histogram of characters (i'm not aware of any approach that use that). But I was considering to encode the words in the "output dictionary". Since the words in the output dictionary don't have a syntactic relationship I think BOW suits better (just an idea).

Comment: So if I use bag of words, then my neural architecture could be 32 input nodes(constant length of the hash) and 26 output nodes(just the length of the alphabet). How about the nodes in the middle or hidden layer? Can it be 32 or depends to me?

Comment: One thing I can comment in BoW is when I have the word "bag" and "gab" they have the save BoW vetor but they have different hash.

Comment: your is an interesting approach. I have never seen a NN using the alphabet as output. I have no clues if it can work :) . The internal design is up to you but I would use less neurons than the input layer to avoid to model the identity function. I would have used the standard approach to encode the BOW with a fixed length and a unique code, so I don't know how help you to solve the ambiguity issue.

Comment: the 26 output nodes refer to the BoW array. there are 26 nodes output since there are 26 alphabets. Im really confused now.

Comment: Yes I have understood that you ara planning to use the output layer to map directly the alphabet. It is just that i'm not sure how it will work. Help me to understand better. The output that you are expecting, (the words in the dictionary) are mapped one to one with the hash keys? i.e. "hash key" -> "word"

Comment: --> yes every word in the dictionary are mapped to hash keys. The hash keys will then be my input to neural net represented by its corresponding ASCII value/256 for each character in the hash. The hash has a constant length of 32 that's why I have 32 input nodes. On the other hand, I am confused how will I represent my output nodes. Could it be a a word vector? or binary representation of the word or bag of words? or any possible encoding?

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. I assume here that each word is equally possible  as output and that the concept of similarity between words is useless ("house","dollhouse","car" are all equally probable and at the same "distance"; this is not the same case in sentences). Under these assumption you can simply use a binary code for your output based on the number of words. 3 words -> 2 bits: "house":00,"dollhouse":01,"car":10. Your output layer will be 2 nodes. Please note that this is feasible if your output dictionary is small. Which is it's size?

Comment: I have a dictionary of 300,000 + .  What could be the possible approach?

Comment: Ok then 19 bits (2^19~500,000+) should be enough to encode your words. Then your output layer will be of 19 nodes. So the approach could be 1) assign a 19 bit code to each word (for a more refined approach you should use a Hamming coding). 2) Train your model using Input: hash (32 neurons) Output: binary code (19 nodes). 3) Associate the predicted code to the original word.

Comment: Ahh ok, I'll try Hamming code. How many hidden nodes do you think I should put on a network with 32 input nodes and 19 output nodes? below 32 or below 19?

Answer (score 1):

There's a great discussion about the possibility of *cracking* SHA256 hashes using neural networks in another Stack Exchange forum: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135211/can-a-neural-network-crack-hashing-algorithms

The accepted answer was that:

> No.
>
> Neural networks are pattern matchers. They're very good pattern
>   matchers, but pattern matchers just the same. No more advanced than
>   the biological brains they are intended to mimic. More thorough, more
>   tireless, but not more sophisticated.
>
> The patterns have to be there to be found. There has to be a bias in
>   the data to tease out. But cryptographic hashes are explicitly and
>   extremely carefully designed to eliminate any bias in the output. No
>   one bit is more likely than any other, no one output is more likely to
>   correlate to any given input. If such a correlation were possible, the
>   hash would be considered "broken" and a new algorithm would take its
>   place.
>
> [Flaws in hash functions have been found before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Broken_hash_functions), but never with the aid
>   of a neural network. Instead it's been with the careful application of
>   certain mathematical principles.

The following answer also makes a funny comparison:

> SHA256 has an output space of 2^256, and an input space that's
>   essentially infinite. For reference, the time since the big bang is
>   estimated to be 5 billion years, which is about 1.577 x 10^27
>   nanoseconds, which is about 2^90 ns. So assuming each training
>   iteration takes 1 ns, you would need 2^166 ages of the universe to
>   train your neural net.